# SQL syntax error in mysql when creating trigger

Tags: mysql

I have a problem when creating a trigger in mysql  i get this error:

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7**

This is my first time creating triggers for mysql help

Here is the code:

```
        CREATE TRIGGER insertAfterUser AFTER INSERT ON MEMBERS    
        FOR EACH ROW    
        BEGIN    
        INSERT INTO blagajna (MemberId,StanjeRacuna) VALUES(12,0.0);    
        END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the delimiter

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER insertAfterUser AFTER INSERT ON MEMBERS    
      FOR EACH ROW    
      BEGIN    
      INSERT INTO blagajna (MemberId,StanjeRacuna) VALUES(12,0.0);    
      END;//
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `insertAfterUser ` BEFORE INSERT ON `members` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO   blagajna (MemberId,StanjeRacuna) VALUES('12','0.0'); END;
```